# Unable to use the apache.poi library after adding gradle dependency

Tags: java, apache, gradle

I've been trying to use the apache.poi library to create an excel file but, for some reason, I'm unable to import anything.

```
mainClassName = 'Main'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev21-1.22.0'

    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.9'
}
```

When I am trying to write import org.apache.poi; it gives me an error saying "Package does not exist".
What is wrong with my dependencies? Thanks.

Comment: If you have exactly " import org.apache.poi;" then the problem is an illegal import statement. You need a wildcard or class. e.g. "import org.apache.poi.*;"

Comment: Did you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some times it is useful to reload a gradle project so gradle could download the binary of the new dependency. After that the new packages should be available.

Comment: If you build your project is there any error output?

Comment: Nevermind, I restarted the IDE and it worked. It did not work after I used "clean and builde".

Comment: Clean and build is not the same than reload project. Reload project is the same as reload pom in an maven project and tells your build tool to check the project dependencies.

Comment: If you restart your ide the build tool does the same

Answer (score 1):

Found the same error while including gradle in the build.gradle file.

Use:
**compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.9'**

```
Like: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fl.gauravsngarg.com.inventory"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After research I found the actual version.

Use 
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.9'

Its given here

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/3.9

The site contains all the official dependencies for gradle, maven, etc.

Comment: even after adding, i am facing problem in import for org.apache.poi

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

It is quite possible that you have enabled gradle sync in **offline mode**.

Just change that.

Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue!

For me File > Invalidate Chaches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart worked.

I am using this version: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.0.0'

Comment: No Mohnish, I just answered the solution with org.apache.poi version 4.0.0 that was helped for me. It's not stealing. 
Come on man, we're here to help each other, not for stealing. 
I believe my explanation will help other guys.